# "Void function definition" error when I press key bound to it

Tags: key-bindings

I added [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7120/5345) function to my `~/.emacs` file and run it by entering `M-x` `my-turn-current-window-into-frame` `RET`.

I added the following to my `~/.emacs` file after that function:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") 'my-turn-current-window-into-frame)
```

I copied that line to `*scratch*` and evaluated it.

When I press <kbd>F12</kbd>, Emacs returns:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: my-turn-current-window-into-frame
```

How can I configure a hot-key to run this function?

Comment: Shouldn't it be (global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") #'my-turn-current-window-into-frame)?

Comment: No... that doesn't work either.

Comment: I assume `M-x my-turn-current-window-into-frame` still works fine, right? Have you tried starting from `emacs -Q`, so it's not something weird in your init file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the problem turned out to be due to a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I did:

- I put this code in my init.el:

  ```el
  (defun my-turn-current-window-into-frame ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((buffer (current-buffer)))
      (unless (one-window-p)
        (delete-window))
      (display-buffer-pop-up-frame buffer nil)))

  (global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") #'my-turn-current-window-into-frame)
  ```
- I restarted Emacs.
- I issued F12.

The current window was turned into a frame.

Comment: This results in the same error as I experience without the `#` character, using Emacs 24.3.1.

Comment: Did you try the code with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Thanks, I have traced the problem to a typo. It now works with or without the `#`.